# What log4net pattern provides for filename without the full path

Tags: c#, log4j, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4cxx

My log4net conversion pattern looks like this

```
<conversionPattern value="%5level [%thread] (%file:%line) - %message%newline" />
```

The %file spits out the full path covering almost one full line in my console window.

How can I get just the file name (minus path).

Right now it looks like this

```
INFO [10] <c:\My Root Dir\Subdir\...........................\filename.cs> - My message
```

I want it to look like

```
INFO [10] <filename.cs> - My message
```

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your own pattern layout converter, maybe like this:

```
public class FileNamePatternConverter : PatternLayoutConverter
{       
    override protected void Convert(TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        writer.Write(Path.GetFileName(loggingEvent.LocationInformation.FileName));
    }
}
```

Then you configure it as follows:

```
<conversionPattern value="%5level [%thread] (%filename:%line) - %message%newline"" />
   <converter>
   <name value="filename" />
   <type value="YourNamespace.FileNamePatternConverter" />
</converter>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget these using statements:

```
using log4net.Layout.Pattern;
using log4net.Core;
```